# An issue with allocating the array at run time

Tags: java

I have a problem when allocating the array at run time, here's what I mean...

```
Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int size;
int[] myarr = new int[size];
size = Scan.nextInt();
```

The problem here is that the array size doesnot update whatsoever.

CLUE: This is a simplified version of a class I'm working on where the size of the array is passed as an argument to the constructor, I cannot declare the array in the main. The array needs to stay an attribute for this class.

Comment: Ask for the size first. Then create your array.

Comment: Your expectations are all wrong. Java is pass by value. Arrays are static types, you cannot resize them.

Comment: Why would you expect it to update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this

```
Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int size;
int[] myarr = new int[size];
size = Scan.nextInt();
```

to

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);//variables in java starts with lower-case by convention
int size =scan.nextInt();
int[] myarr = new int[size];
```

Note that arrays are fixed-size, you cannot change size dinamically at runtime without creating a new one.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment you do

```
int[] myarr = new int[size];
```

the variable `size` is already declared, but *not initialized*. You should initialize it *before* you use it:

```
Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int size = Scan.nextInt();
int[] myarr = new int[size];
```

**Note:**

- After you have created the array `myarr` *its size can't be changed*. If you wanted to change the size, you can create a new array with the desired size or use another structure like an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int size= Scan.nextInt();
int[] myarr = new int[size];
```

You defined the size after instantiating the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize your field very frequently, you most likely do not want to use an array because it cannot be resized. As mentioned in one of the comments above, you could use `ArrayList`.Yet, it is still a `List` which is internally an array: Even though you do not have to deal with resizing it *by hand*, the JVM does it internally - this may result in bad runtime behaviour (still assuming that resizing is your top priority).

If resizing the `List` very often you may want to take a look at more dynamic structures like a `LinkedList` instead.

However, this decision is always based on how you are going to use your `List` and what your primary objectives are.